# IntelliSense doesn't show partial class method

Tags: c#, linq, intellisense

I have partial class User generated by LINQtoSQL as shortly following:

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.[User]")]
public partial class User : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);
 ...
```

Then I created separate folder "Proxy" in my project and put there extra piece of User class:

```
namespace LINQtoSQL_sample.Proxy
{
    public partial class User
    {
        public static string GetActivationUrl()
        {
            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
         ...
```

Issue happens when I try to invoke that extra static method from another part of same project. Let's say I have once more folder "SqlRepositoryImpl" and another one partial class there:

```
namespace LINQtoSQL_sample.SqlRepositoryImpl
{
    public partial class SqlRepository
    {
        public bool CreateUser(User instance)
        {
            if (instance.ID == 0)
            {
                instance.added_date = DateTime.Now;
                instance.activated_link = LINQtoSQL_sample.Proxy.User.GetActivationUrl();
              ...
```

As you can see I explicitly defined which part of User class I'm calling for because IntelliSense didn't suggest me my extra method.

Please, advise why such happens and where I'm wrong?

Comment: Make sure both partial User classes are in the same  namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you can see I explicitly defined which part of User class I'm calling for because IntelliSense didn't suggest me my extra method.

When you call a method from a class, there are no “parts” of the class anymore.

If you need to (and can) specify the full namespace of the class to invoke a method from it that means you actually have two different classes in two different namespaces. If the two `partial` declarations are in different namespaces, then you have actually declared two separate classes, not a single class from two parts.